# /Index.cshtml: is an empty page?

Tags: razor, razor-pages, razorengine

According to msdn tutorials,/web app/razor pages/, Pages were set up , when examine [Pages/Movies/Index.cshtml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) Razor Page or so: It was shown an empty page at vs2017. and I can even write no a word to the page.
What's matter?
Thanks,

Comment: Do you have the _layout pages?

Comment: Yes, of cause, under the project! Pages/Shared/_layout.cshtml.